# A VB6 application locks up when shut down via the restart manager

Tags: vb6, installation

I'm having a problem with a VB6 app locking up when it is shutdown via the Windows [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
This is very visible when using the new Restart Manager support in Inno setup and even occurs with an empty VB6 project compiled.

When I've added logging to the `QueryUnload` and `Unload` event, I see the following sequence:

```
QueryUnload(vbAppWindows)
Unload()
QueryUnload(vbAppTaskManager)
```

After this, the VB6 process seems to lock up inside the VB6 runtime and the process calling the Restart Manager eventually times out and gives up.

A similar problem has been reported [before](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/MCyT4bVyuvc/discussion) buit with no sensible resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were discussions on this in 2007 on the [Windows Application Compatability](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/affa5776-4c0d-4d71-b7f1-4141458c3589) forums.

The proposed solution was to add this to the end of the `QueryUnload` event handler of your main form:

```
'For Vista Certification requirement.
'Handles TEST CASE 30. Verify the application is Restart Manager Aware.
If UnloadMode = vbAppWindows Then Unload Me
```

It seems that the VB6 runtime isn't handling one of the shutdown messages correctly and so the Restart Manager then sends a more forcable close message causing the runtime to lock up.

I have confirmed this fix with a fairly complex, multi process VB6 application and it all shuts down correctly with no obvious untoward affects.

Comment: +1. It was also [discussed in 2010](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!searchin/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/%22restart$20manager%22/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/MCyT4bVyuvc/etTVRsmJ5mwJ) by the gurus on the VB6 newsgroup, with a similar conclusion

Comment: Ah yes, I was involved in that thread, unbeknowingly to me when I needed to find out myself 2 years later :) I've updated the question to link to GG rather than the NNTP scraper I found first.